# How can I retrieve a value from IsolatedStorage in other class?

Tags: class, windows-phone-7, boolean, isolatedstorage

I have two classes. First is using for store boolean value from ToggleSwitchButton by using IsolatedStorage.

Like this...

```
    private void tglSwitch_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["EnableLocation"] = true;  
    }
    private void tglSwitch_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["EnableLocation"] = false;
    }
```

The second class will use the boolean value from the first class to do something.

Like this...

```
     if(booleanValFromFirst){
        //Do something
     }
     else{
        //Do something
     }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this, what you want?

```
if ((bool)System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["EnableLocation"] == true)
```

P.S. I would recommend for you to create a single class for all values, stored in Application Settings and work with it.

Like this:

```
public static class SettingsManager
    {
        private static IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings;

        public static IsolatedStorageSettings AppSettings
        {
            get { return SettingsManager.appSettings; }
            set { SettingsManager.appSettings = value; }
        }

        public static void LoadSettings()
        {
            // Constructor
            if (appSettings == null)
                appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

            // Generate Keys if not created
            if (!appSettings.Contains(Constants.SomeKey))
                appSettings[Constants.SomeKey] = "Some Default value";

            // generate other keys             

       }
   }
```

Then you can work with that class instance

Initialize it at your startup class as `SettingsManager.LoadSettings();`

an then in any class just call for it:

```
if ((bool)SettingsManager.AppSettings[Constants.SomeBoolKey])
     doSomething();
```